# Mock static method in spock

Tags: java, testing, groovy, mockito, spock

I try to mock static method with mockito-inline in spock

```
given:
    try(MockedStatic<CryptoUtils> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(CryptoUtils.class)){
                mockedStatic.when({ -> CryptoUtils.decryptWithPrefixIV(any() as String, any() as String) }).thenReturn(word)
            }
```

But this doesnt work --- 'try' with resources is not supported in current version

Answer (score 3):

You technically can put try with resources in spock test,

Groovy 3+ supports try..with..resources: [ARM Try with resources](https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#_arm_try_with_resources)

and spock pulls Groovy 3:
See https://spockframework.org/

> testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-groovy-3.0"

On the other hand, the mockStatic is active only to the moment when it is closed, which does not compose with Spock's blocks. Thus, usage of [cleanup block](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/spock_primer.html#_cleanup_blocks) may be preferred

> Like a cleanup method, it is used to free any resources used by a feature method, and is run even if (a previous part of) the feature method has produced an exception. As a consequence, a cleanup block must be coded defensively; in the worst case, it must gracefully handle the situation where the first statement in a feature method has thrown an exception, and all local variables still have their default values.

```groovy
class Test {
  static max(int a, int b) {
    return Math.max(a, b)
  }
}

def "testMockStatic"() {
  given:
  var mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Test.class)
  mockedStatic.when({ -> Test.max(2, 3) }).thenReturn(10)

  expect:
  Test.max(2, 3) == 10

  cleanup:
  mockedStatic?.close()
}
```

As cleanup block is executed even if exception is thrown, you may have a code that throws before mockStatic - in this case `mockedStatic` is null. Spock advises defensive coding for this case:

> As a consequence, a cleanup block must be coded defensively; in the worst case, it must gracefully handle the situation where the first statement in a feature method has thrown an exception, and all local variables still have their default values.
>
> Groovy’s safe dereference operator `(foo?.bar())` simplifies writing defensive code.

Comment: _"Spock pulls Groovy 3":_ While this is true for `2.0-groovy-3.0`, there is also a version `2.0-groovy-2.5`. Maybe the OP used that one or he simply used Spock 1.3. He did not specify. Great answer otherwise.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for in my upgrade to `2.2-M1-groovy-3.0`. I had tried to still use PowerMock for 1 test but the suggested alternative to Sputnik (JUnitRuntime) didn't work for me. Instead embraced the new Mockito power and this was the last piece to the puzzle.